# How to modify recv to implement IO/ non-blocking?

Tags: c, nonblocking, asyncsocket, recv

I'm trying to write a server in C, with I/O non-blocking because sometimes it goes down for flood requests.
Looking around, I've notice that I/O non-blocking can solve my problem.
Reading the Beej guide, I've implemented the recvtimeout function, that set a timeout to handle data from a client.
People told me I have to use the **select** to avoid this problem, but I used it already in the function recvtimeout:

```
int Server::recvtimeout(int s, char *buf, int len, int timeout)
    {

    //Check if non-blocking
    fcntl(s, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
int flags = fcntl(s, F_GETFD);
if ((flags & O_NONBLOCK) == O_NONBLOCK) {
  fprintf(stderr, "nonblocking active");
}
else {
  fprintf(stderr, "nonblocking not active");
}
    //End check

fd_set fds;
int n;
struct timeval tv;
// set up the file descriptor set
FD_ZERO(&fds);
FD_SET(s, &fds);
// set up the struct timeval for the timeout
tv.tv_sec = timeout;
tv.tv_usec = 0;
// wait until timeout or data received
n = select(s+1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
if (n == 0){
    return -2; // timeout!
}
if (n == -1){
    return -1; // error
}
// data must be here, so do a normal recv()
return recv(s, buf, len, 0);
    }
```

So, I've added a piece of code that show me if NONBLOCK is set or not, but never I read *nonblocking active*, so in my code nonblocking is not active.
How can I mod my code to enable this?

The problem is when I read a string from a client and have a code like this:

```
        char headerstring[512];
    memset(headerstring,0,512);
    if(this->recvtimeout(client_fd,headerstring,sizeof(headerstring),10) < 0){
        close(client_fd);
    }
```

All works fine, but with a flooder that close the connection during the transaction, the server goes down.
I've tried try-catch and any other things...but nothing.

Comment: *Reading the Beej guide, ....*  Are you referring to that kid at Chico State who wrote that neat IPC tutorial back in the 1990s?  Beej (Brian Hall?) isn't a kid any more, I suppose (come to think of it, neither am I), but I had no idea that anyone still remembered that tutorial.

Comment: I dunno, but my code works fine with that book, doesn't depend from oldness because unix socket are in early sixty.

Comment: Beej made that tutorial a book, did he?  I hadn't known that.  I remember it as a web page at Chico State U.  In fact, I was so impressed with the web page that I cached a copy of it, and still keep the copy handy.  Beej had the page posted up alongside his Internet Pizza Server, as I recall.

Comment: talking about this? http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html

Answer (score 1):

The normal way to set a socket to non-blocking is

```
  int x;
  x=fcntl(s,F_GETFL,0);
  fcntl(s,F_SETFL,x | O_NONBLOCK);
```

In your code you are getting the flags using

```
int flags = fcntl(s, F_GETFD);
```

whereas you should be doing as

```
  x=fcntl(s,F_GETFL,0);
```

So, non-blocking may actually be getting enabled on your socket.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things:

1. After `select()` call:

   ```
   if(n < 0) continue;
   if(FD_ISSET(s, &fds)) { //check if Socket ready for reading
      FD_CLR(s, &fds);  // Clear for next time
      // call recv()
   }
   ```
2. Set socket as non-blocking like this:

   ```
   /* set socket as non-blocking */
   int x = fcntl(s, F_GETFL, 0);
   fcntl(s, F_SETFL, x | O_NONBLOCK);
   ```